# Xcode 9.1 Simulator Crashes macOS System

Tags: xcode, crash, ios-simulator, hackintosh, xcode9.1

I'm running macOS Sierra, but same experienced on High Sierra.

When I open the Simulator in Xcode 9.1, it doesn't load anything (sometimes a red screen), however crashes the whole system. I can move the mouse, but everything is unclickable.

Really rarely it receives clicks and I can open the Activity Monitor to shut it down. Restart doesn't help, because Simulator is reopened then, and crashes the whole system again.

Is there anyone out there experiencing the same issue? Any solutions, suggestions?

Could this relate to the fact that I have a Hackintosh?

Comment: This question is too broad and in its current state, it's more suitable on [su]. Include some crash logs and more background information.

Comment: Why you people do this? I would like to know if anybody have the same problem. In my opinion, millions of users should! But if you down vote my question, it will be more less likely to reach them! Why would you do that, man?!

Comment: I experienced this on more than one computer. So this IS indeed a REALLY broad problem, and should be addressed!

Comment: How on earth do you expect crash logs if I can barely make the OS operational again?!

Comment: I wanted to reach people, who have EXPERIENCE in this! And NOT people who help me read crash logs!

Comment: I have no account on SuperUser, so I cannot post questions there for sure! I read similar issues here, so I disagree. This questions has its place here.

Comment: Please, pretty please. Remove this down vote. Please don't ruin my day! I need answers!

Comment: There are lots of historical/wrongly categorized questions on Stack Overflow that are not on-topic at all and need moderation. In general, do not take a comment/downvote personally. If general user feedback shows that a question needs improvement, take the adivce - it *will* help others to find your question. You can document this problem more broadly with the help of Console.app (take a look at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26480/where-can-i-find-my-crash-logs)).

Comment: Try updating to Xcode 9.2 (currently in beta). If the problem persists there, please file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Please provide some info about your PC's specification. I'm also using Hackintosh, and solved the Xcode crashes/Simulator problems, but the solution depends on the bootloader settings and the PC components you have. And yes, the crash is because you're running a Hackintosh and the kexts/bootloader settings are partialy or fully wrong.

Comment: Motherboard: Gigabyte Z68P-DS3-B3 s1155
Processor: Intel Core i3-2100 3.1 GHz
Memory: Corsair XMS3 8GB 1600MHz Dual Kit RAM
Videocard: Asus HD6870 1GB GDDR5 PCIe

Answer (score 0):

We can't provide support for pirate copies of macOS running on non-Apple hardware. I would encourage you to purchase authorized Apple hardware which comes with a legal copy of macOS.

Red is the canary texture indicating the GPU didn't write anything to the surface. It is probably a rendering failure due to graphics driver bugs. You can check the logs in cases where it doesn't fully restart and you may find GPU restarts are taking place. If the GPU restart fails then the system will panic and reboot.

Edit: As I previously indicated, you're running untested hardware on a hacked copy of macOS using unknown drivers. If you're using built-in drivers it may be a mis-match between the hardware they expect and the GPU you have. If you're using vendor-provided drivers it may be a simple bug. And when running any non-standard kernels or kernel extensions there could be a vast array of possible causes (bad kernel extension corrupting some data structure, etc)

Comment: Very interesting comment, but probably this _is_ a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @matt A red canary texture, GPU restart (as indicated by the cursor plane still being operational), and sometimes panic restarts is almost certainly a graphics driver bug as I indicated. That seems like an answer to me.

Comment: @cramopy The OP asked if this is related to having a hackintosh. The answer is _yes_. I also provided a likely root cause: GPU driver bug or mis-match. I work on the Simulator so I don't typically post questions about it to SO but I appreciate your attempt to be helpful - I think it is important to keep SO as a welcoming place for all contributors.

Comment: @russbishop very polite comment :) indeed, you are answering the last part of the question (with a "yes"). Thus it looked to me more like a comment than an answer. Whilst the content is totally valid and valuable, this also results from a bad asked question with subquestions. But l left an upvote for your reasonable and valuable response to the question :)